# How to parse json using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am Using web service in with Jquery Ajax this returning me the following string

```
{"d":"[{\"username\":\"ABC\",\"designation\":\"\"}]"}
```

but when I am trying to parse this it is giving me error

```js
var response = '{"d":"[{\"username\":\"ABC\",\"designation\":\"\"}]"}';

console.log(JSON.parse(response));
```

Comment: That's invalid json.  The `[]` should not have quotes around them, and quotes should not be escaped.  How was this json generated?

Comment: Can you please share more code (what have you tried so far)  and exact error message?

Comment: I am calling web service given by other customer ....and I have to extract data from it by giving Jquery Ajax Call

Comment: var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);  //result Means {"d":"[{\"username\":\"ABC\",\"designation\":\"\"}]"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, you need to remove the quotes around the braces.

```js
const PATTERNS = [/"(\[)/g, /(\])"/g]; // Invalid patterns
const JsonFixer = json => PATTERNS.reduce((s, re) => s.replace(re, '$1'), json);

var rawJsonResponse = '{"d":"[{\"username\":\"ABC\",\"designation\":\"\"}]"}';

console.log(JSON.parse(JsonFixer(rawJsonResponse)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```